# Can you secure an Elasticsearch cluster on a remote EC2 instance with a security group?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have a rails application that uses elasticsearch via the gem 'elasticsearch-rails', '~> 7.2.0'. Elasticsearch is hosted on a difference ec2 instance than the rails application. Both EC2 instances reside in the same VPC and Subnet but, have their own security groups and have restrictive inbound and outbound rules that allow them to communicate with each other (the elasticsearch instance can only receive traffic from the application instance).

The elasticsearch cluster (single node) is not currently configured to use TLS, SSL, or Authentication. Is it correct to assume that the elasticsearch cluster is secure due to the security group? I do however understand that if the application server is compromised then actor will have unlimited access to the elasticsearch cluster. Is it also correct to assume that the communication between the two instances are secure and not susceptible to interception, due to them sharing a VPC and Subnet?

Comment: By secure you mean not accessible from the internet?

Comment: I thought that might be a bit too ambiguous. By secure I mean a few things, not accessible by the internet outside the application facilitated interactions, communication not able to be intercepted, impersonated or monitored.

Comment: Are you the only one using the VPC and/or your account?

Comment: Its a VPC facilitated by AWS, so it only being used by those two EC2 instances.

Comment: In that case that's fine.